# Colorbar labels cutoff when using unicode

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode

In matploblib the following code gives me labels in the colorbar that are clipped

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(img)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([u'\u2192', u'\u2198', u'\u2193', u'\u2199', 
                         u'\u2190', u'\u2196', u'\u2191', u'\u2197'], size=20)
```

Like these clipped arrows:

[image: example]

Any advice?

Thanks!

This is with python 2.7, matplotlib 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what could cause this strange behaviour.

A workaround is to add a space (`" "`) after each label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(img)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
ticklabels = [u'\u2192', u'\u2198', u'\u2193', u'\u2199', 
                         u'\u2190', u'\u2196', u'\u2191', u'\u2197']
ticklabels = [t + " " for t in ticklabels]
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(ticklabels, size=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]